# How do I display JSON data to appear as a list view in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have been working on solving an exception error(FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)) that is present at the json.decode(response.body) section of the code.  I have no idea on how I can solve that. Any response from you guys is highly appreciated. Below is the code:

```
 Future<List<Garage>> garagesFuture = getGarages();
  static Future<List<Garage>> getGarages() async {
    const url =
        'https://console.firebase.google.com/project/atta-web-app-a5135/database/atta-web-app-a5135-default-rtdb/data/~2FGarages';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final body = json.decode(response.body);
    return body.map<Garage>(Garage.fromJson).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ref = dref.ref().child('Garages');
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Garage>>(
          future: garagesFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final garages = snapshot.data!;
              return buildGarage(garages);
            } else {
              return const Text('No Garages Available');
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  buildGarage(List<Garage> garages) {
    ListView.builder(
        itemCount: garages.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final garage = garages[index];
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(garage.garageName),
              subtitle: Text(garage.officeNumber),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: ((context) => const MessageCenter())));
              },
            ),
```

Comment: add your api response.

Comment: @ManishDayma how do I do that?

Comment: it seems that you are trying to access your realtime database on firebase thru http which is a problem... here is a link of the docs for firebase usage in flutter: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/overview.

Comment: okay print the response in console and paste here

Comment: could you print("body = ${response.body}"); before this: final body = json.decode(response.body); and add the result to question?

Answer (score 0):

Seems your problem with decoder.

Try using

```
json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes))
```

to convert the encoding to utf8